# Is lambda expression only applicable for functional interface?

Tags: java, java-8

I have just started learning java 8. There I read that lambda expression can only be applied to functional interfaces.
But below code, I see from a java site. Here it is using MathOperation class and referring its methods using lambda expression, not referring to any method of a functional interface. If someone helps me understand it, it would be great.

```
package com.jcg.java;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;

class MathOperation {

    /**** Addition ****/
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    /**** Subtraction ****/
    public int sub(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}

/***** Reference To An Instance Method Of A Particular Object *****/
public class MethodReferenceEx2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MathOperation op = new MathOperation();

        /**** Using Lambda Expression ****/
        System.out.println("--------------------Using Lambda Expression----------------------");
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add1 = (a, b) -> op.add(a, b);
        System.out.println("Addtion = " + add1.apply(4, 5));

        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sub1 = (a, b) -> op.sub(a, b);
        System.out.println("Subtraction = " + sub1.apply(58, 5));

        /**** Using Method Reference ****/
        System.out.println("\n---------------------Using Method Reference---------------------");
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add2 = op::add;
        System.out.println("Addtion = " + add2.apply(4, 5));

        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sub2 = op::sub;
        System.out.println("Subtraction = " + sub2.apply(58, 5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that sane people would use `IntBinaryOperator` rather than `BinaryFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`. Given that the tutorial seems to be written by someone less than sane, perhaps find a better one.

Comment: @Boris, thanks. Noted.

Answer (score 2):

> Here it is using MathOperation class and referring its methods using lambda expression, not referring to any method of a functional interface.

No, all the lambda expressions in this code implement the `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` function interface.

The body of the lambda expressions is allowed to call methods of the `MathOperation` class. It doesn't have to refer only to methods of a functional interface.

When you wish to execute the method of the functional interface instance implemented by the lambda expression, you call the functional interface's method, as in `sub2.apply(58, 5)`.

Comment: @user1988 if this answer answered your question, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, BiFunction is a functional interface... so, with "BiFunction add1 = (a, b) -> op.add(a, b);"  you are implementing the apply() method signature! so you are right! with lambda you can just implement interfaces with one abstract method:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html

Comment: Thank for sharing the link

Answer (score -2):

We can use lambda expressions for normal classes also.

Ex:

```
public class Employee{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private int salary;
}
```

when we want to retrieve employee details whose age is >20, then we write like below

emplist.stream().filter(x -> x.getAge()>20).collect(Collectors.toList());

here we have applied lamda expression on employee class (x-> x.getAge() >20)  which is not a functional interface.

Comment: Obviously, your answer is showing completely wrong concept because `filter` method of `Stream` interface requires the parameter `Predicate` which is a functional interface.